Angular - Email pattern validation
<label for="userEmail">User Email:</label><br />
<input type="email" class="userMobile" id="userEmail" name="userEmail"
  [(ngModel)]="selectedLocker.lockeruseremail" required 
  pattern="[a-z0-9._%+-]+@[a-z0-9.-]+\.(com|in)$"/><br />

The pattern requires the email to be in the format "example@example.com" or "example@example.in", but it still allows submission without ".com" or ".in".

Can you provide the rest of the code instead of just the inputs so we can understand the logic and what the issue is?

For the template-driven form, you should use form.valid to check the form is valid before submission. And apply the [disabled] attribute to block the button submission.
import { ViewChild } from '@angular/core';
import { NgForm } from '@angular/forms';

@ViewChild('form') form!: NgForm;

submit() {
  if (!this.form.valid) {
    alert('Form value invalid Detected!')
    return;
  }

  ...
}

You can display the error for the control with the ngModel directive as below:
<form #form="ngForm" (submit)="submit()">
  <label for="userEmail">User Email:</label><br />
  <input
    type="email"
    class="userMobile"
    id="userEmail"
    name="userEmail"
    [(ngModel)]="selectedLocker.lockeruseremail"
    required
    pattern="[a-z0-9._%+-]+@[a-z0-9.-]+\.(com|in)$"
    #email="ngModel"
  /><br />
  <ng-container *ngIf="email.errors?.pattern">
    Invalid email pattern.
  </ng-container>

  <button [disabled]="!form.form.valid">Submit</button>
</form>

Demo @ StackBlitz

Works like charm, thanks bro

This email validation pattern has several issues, try to use this pattern :
^[a-zA-Z0-9._%+-]+@[a-zA-Z0-9.-]+\.[a-zA-Z]{2,}$

